# C++ - Do I have to recalculate private variable equations for every function?

Tags: c++, function, variables

I'm somewhat new to programming and I am developing a small rpg battle system to practice my skills. I'm not sure how to logically solve this seemingly simple problem I am having. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do that wont work:

```
class ExampleClass{

public:

int getDamage(int SwordPower)
{
    Weapon = SwordPower;
    cout << Damage;
    return Damage;
}

private:
int Weapon = 0;
int Strength = 5;
int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);
};

int main()
{
    ExampleClass Character;
    Character.getDamage(45);
}
```

The damage output ends up being 0 when it should be 225, presumably because the Damage variable is returning its originally defined value of 0 rather than returning the intended new value because getDamage did not ask it to recalculate using the new value of Weapon defined by the parameter.

What I have been doing so far that DOES WORK is this:

```
int getDamage(int SwordPower)
    {
        Weapon = SwordPower;
        Damage = (Weapon*Strength);
        cout << Damage;
        return Damage;
    }

    private:
    int Weapon = 0;
    int Strength = 5;
    int Damage = 0;
    };
```

This outputs 225, the correct number, because the new Weapon value is used to recalculate Damage. However, this means that I have to declare `Damage = (Weapon*Strength);` in every single function, rather than simply having it predefined for every function in the class. This is a big deal because the dozens of classes I have been making have dozens of significantly longer and more complex functions, and dozens of these equation-defined variables per function, so doing it this way feels really inefficient.

Is there a better, more obvious way I'm missing?

Comment: You seem to believe that, by writing `int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);`, you define a data member named `Damage` whose value is somehow magically always equal to `Weapon*Strength`. That's not how C++ works. The closest you can get to this is make `Damage` a member function: `int Damage() { return Weapon * Strength; }`. Then you use it as `cout << Damage(); return Damage();`

Comment: First of all I agree with @IgorTandetnik. The second thing is that getDamage() should not change the private member... its name is `get`. Make simple methods, don't overload them too much. Create `void setWeapon(const int weapon_val) { Weapon = weapon_val;}` and create `int Damage() const { return Weapon * Strength; }` or  `int getDamage() const { return Weapon * Strength; }`

Comment: +1 @AlexLop and further suggestions is that this is a strong argument for inheritance. You could have a base `ExampleClass`... probably rename it though :) and then derive your other classes from `ExampleClass`. So when each class is created it will be created with its own specific attributes to are unique to the class

Answer (score 0):

For this example you do not need Weapon and Damage members at all.

```
//...

int getDamage(int weapon)
{
    int damage = weapon * Strength;
    cout<<damage<<endl;
    return damage;
}

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

First code you have written is not working because it is not exactly what you think it is.

```
class ExampleClass{
    int Weapon = 0;
    int Strength = 5;
    int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);
};
```

Giving values to class variables like this only means this calculations are done during the creation of an object from the class. 
So when you instantiate the `Character` from `ExampleClass` the `Damage` is set to `0`

So you should be recalculating the Damage in code.

```
class ExampleClass{
    int Weapon = 0;
    int Strength = 5;
    //int Damage = 0; is practically the same thing 
    int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);

    public void setWeaponDamage(int SwordDamage){
          Weapon = SwordDamage;
    }
    public int getDamage(){
          return (Weapon * Strength);
    }
    //Maybe something like this if you need to use the "Damage" variable
    //although doesn't seem like you would need.
    public void setDamage(int damage){
          Damage = damage;
    }
};
```

Considering @Thomas Matthews' comment, I removed (this->) notation.

Comment: BTW, common rule of thumb is to avoid `this->` syntax.  You only need it if the parameter name is the same as the class member name.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, thank you for the advice, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could define member function `setWeapon` that recalculates Damage every time when a new value is assigned to Weapon.

For example

```
void setWeapon( int w )
{
   if ( this->Weapon != w )
   {
      this->Weapon = w;
      this->Damage = this->Weapon * thsi->Strength;
   }
}
```

then this member function could be used in `getDamage`

```
int getDamage( int SwordPower )
{
    setWeapon( SwordPower );
    return Damage;
}
```

As for this initialization

```
private:
int Weapon = 0;
int Strength = 5;
int Damage = 0;
```

or this

```
private:
int Weapon = 0;
int Strength = 5;
int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);
```

then it is performed only once when an object of the class is created calling the default constructor.

So there is no great sense to write

```
int Damage = (Weapon*Strength);
```

if Weapon is initialized by 0.

I think it would be better to use C# for your program that provides properties.:)

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual C++ style to have a function called `getSomething` that also sets something (in this case the `Weapon`.

It is generally considered good practice if member functions have one and only one responsibility. I suggest you have two member functions, one called something like `setWeapon` that returns nothing and another called `getDamage` which calculates the damage and doesn't modify the class:

```
class ExampleClass{
public:
    void setWeapon(int newWeapon)
    {
        weapon = newWeapon;
    }

    int getDamage() const 
    {
        return weapon*strength;
    }
private:
    int weapon = 0;
    int strength = 5;
};

int main()
{
    ExampleClass character;
    character.setWeapon(45);
    std::cout << character.getDamage() << "\n";
}
```

Then the code to calculate the damage is written in one place, the `getDamage` member function. This way you minimise the size of your class (two ints).

If it turns out you are calculating damage a lot then an optimization might be to add a cache for the damage but you have to make sure to update your cache if weapon or strength changes and be aware that this will increase the size of your class to three ints:

```
class ExampleClass{
public:
    void setWeapon(int newWeapon)
    {
        weapon = newWeapon;
        updateDamage();
    }

    void setStrength(int newStrength)
    {
        strength = newStrength;
        updateDamage();
    }    

    int getDamage() const 
    {
        return damage;
    }

private:
    void updateDamage() const {
        damage = weapon*strength;
    }

    int weapon = 0;
    int strength = 5;
    mutable int damage = 0;
};
```

But I would only do this if you had some evidence it was needed.

You might be able to optimize this further by only calculating the damage when it is needed and storing it for subsequent use.